# how to allow nullable properties on model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When a new user is registered he doesn't need to fill 'Address' & 'DoB' properties. However, when I redirect him to 'Edit Profile' page I'm getting an error: nullable object must have a value. So, its not crashing if user has those properties set. But I want those properties to be optional.
I thought the solution might be when the user to sign up, to set those values to:

```
            Address = "",
            Dob = null,
```

But still I'm getting an error.

Any other solution on this?

[image]

Comment: "Any other solution on this?" - yes: **you should not be using your DB entity models as view-models or form-models**. They represent completely different things, even though they contain common and similar members (and don't think about using inheritance either).

Comment: Also... what happens if your user is not male?

Comment: You should _probably not_ be using `nvarchar(max)` for all of your columns - you can easily accidentally end-up with tens-of-megabytes of text in a column (this has happened to me). Constraints and max-lengths exist for a reason. For example, an email address will rarely be over 255 chars, so your email column should be `nvarchar(255)`. For textual columns you should make them `NOT NULL` and just use an empty-string value to represent no-data. You should avoid having any NULLable columns in your database where-possible.

Comment: DOB is a date... why are you storing it as a `datetime2` value? If you _do_ care about time-of-birth then you should be using `datetimeoffset` instead because that time will be zone-sensitive. (and you **are** consistently storing datetime values in UTC, right?)

Comment: ...what is your `PwdGuid` column? Why aren't you hashing passwords to a fixed-size `binary` column that suits your hash algo, such as `binary(32)` with SHA-256 (ditto the salt column).

Comment: 1. I'm not using entity models as view models. 2. nvarchar(255) is good advice, I just changed that. 3. DoB is date, this might have been string which could be easier. 3. PwdGuid is a field if the user wants to change his password, and reset it via email, its working fine now. | I had to set default datetime so it wont crash the app

Comment: "this might have been string which could be easier" - **never** store dates and times as strings - yegods?! what makes you think that's a good idea?

Comment: You need to post the full stack-trace of the exception you're getting and **use your debugger**.

Answer (score 0):

try use `DbNull.Value` instead of null